# Challenge with merging two params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, url-parameters

I have following entry in my routes for subcategory**(a.k.a. type)** pages:

```
match '/jewellery/:taxon/(:tag)' => 'shop#index', :as => 'shop'
```

I also have a set of filters (type, material, plating etc) on the subcategory pages. So, consider a taxon "Earrings". I have following subcategories in this taxon - "Danglers", "Hoops", "Studs".
So, the corresponding subcategory pages are "/jewellery/earrings/danglers", "/jewellery/earrings/hoops" and "/jewellery/earrings/studs".

I want a functionality that if a user goes to sub-category page, the corresponding checkbox in the type filter should be checked. So, if I go to "/jewellery/earrings/studs" the checkbox labelled "Studs" should be checked by default. I want to allow multiple type selection, so input from filters needs to be an array. I have the following code:

```
            <% Typelabels.each { |label| %>
              <%if filter[:name] == "Type"%>
                <% if (!params["type"].nil? && (params["type"].member? label)) 
                        or (!params[:tag].nil? && params[:tag].gsub(/[+-]/," ") == label.downcase)%>
                  <input type="checkbox" id='<%= label.to_s %>' name="type[]" value="<%= label %>" checked />
                  <label for="<%= label.to_s %>" class="<%= t %>_name_label"><%= label%></label>
                <%else%>
                  <input type="checkbox" id='<%= label.to_s %>' name="type[]" value="<%= label %>"/>
                  <label for="<%= label.to_s %>" class="<%= t %>_name_label"><%= label%></label>
                <%end%>
              <% end %>
              <%}%>
```

But challenge is that when I un-check the box "Studs" (which was checked by default, on "/jewellery/earrings/studs"), I get redirected to the same page as the `tag` in params is fixed.

Please can someone help me

Comment: this code suffers from a huge lack of abstraction, really unreadable

Comment: @apneadiving : I have tried to make it simpler

Comment: you should use intermediate objects like presenters to remove all this logic fomr your views